# Linux Grep Probably Simple Answer

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, awk, grep

I am working with the `zone.tab` under `/usr/share/zoneinfo/zonetab` and I am having trouble displaying the data in a certain format.

the command I run:

```
cat zone.tab | awk '!/#/ {print $3}' | sort
```

this returns a list of regions and contries:

```
America/Washington
Pacific/Enderbury
```

What I need is for the above to return everything after the last `/` on each line.

There are some cases such as `Pacific/Somewhere/A`. I have a regex (`[^/]+$`) that should work but it doesn't. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can also do it all in a single `awk` command:

```
awk '!/^#/ { sub(".*/", "", $3); print $3 }' /usr/share/zoneinfo/zone.tab
     ----    -----------------   --------
        |                   |          |
  for non-comment lines     |          |
                            |          |
                     modify 3rd col    |
                   leaving only text   |
                   after last slash    |
                                       |
                                 Then print modified 3rd col
```

Answer (score 1):

Pipe the output to `sed -e 's;^.*/;;'`. For example,

```
echo -e "America/Washington\nPacific/Enderbury" | sed 's;^.*/;;'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
sed s:.*/:: /usr/share/zoneinfo/zone.tab
```

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '!/^#/ { print $3;} ' < /usr/share/zoneinfo/zone.tab   | awk -F/ ' { print $NF; }'
```

Answer (score 1):

This regex might work:

```
# echo -e "a\n\a/b\na/b/c\na/b/c/d\n" |sed 's#^\(\([^/]*/\)*\)\(.*\)#\3#'
a
b
c
d
```

Perhaps `sed -r 's#^(([^/]*/)*)(.*)#\3#'` which removes the tangle of backslashes is clearer.